# Localization of personal page on GitHub. Which solution to choose?

Tags: github, localization, web, github-pages

I have a personal page on GitHub ( myusername.github.io ). I want to make several versions, EN (global), RU (local), etc. How is it better to implement?

The first thing that came to mind - just create index-XX.html, where XX - language ID, and then on all pages make a redirect to localized pages. But in this case I duplicating the same page. Of course, I did not plan to update the pages every day, but I want to make things right.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your framework.

With Jekyll/Octopress, you have [`octopress/multilingual`](https://github.com/octopress/multilingual)

> If you have not specified a permalink style, or if you are using one of Jekyll's default templates, your post URLs will change to include their language.
>   When using Jekyll's pretty url template, URLs will look like this:

```
/site_updates/en/2015/01/17/moving-to-a-multilingual-site/index.html
/site_updates/de/2015/01/17/umzug-in-eine-mehrsprachige-website/index.html
```

If you are using a [static-site generator like Hugo](http://gohugo.io/), there is a [Pull Request in progress](https://github.com/spf13/hugo/pull/1734)

> support having language switchers in templates, that know where the translated page is (with `.Page.Translations`)
>   (when you're on `/en/about/`, there's a "Francais" link that points to `/fr/a-propos`)